# Is there a way to track the amount of Opens of a specific email from specific contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, subscriber

I am trying to measure how many times did each subscriber opened a particular email. I find metric for Opens vs Unique Opens, but for all the subscribers targeted, and not for each subscriber individually. Is there any chance I could track this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5) to retrieve this information. In the Open one, for example, you have the information about if the open is unique or not (IsUnique field) and as it is a transactional table you can have the date of each click (EventDate field).